# How to enable features, like token-exchange, in keycloak from command line

Tags: docker, keycloak

I tried to implement **user impersonation** with Keycloak but I got this error

```
"error": "Feature not enabled"
```

This image shows what I ran in Postman and the error:

[image]

To start keycloak I ran Docker, on Windows 10 and then this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin123 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e DB_VENDOR=H2 jboss/keycloak
```

so I use jBoss docker image, from RedHat.

So I wanted to enable that missing feature in keycloak, but from [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features) I can't understand where to run this specific command:

```
For example, to enable docker and token-exchange, enter this command:

bin/kc.[sh|bat] build --features=docker,token-exchange
```

to have, for example, this **token-exchange** feature available in keycloak.

I tried to find into jBoss this kc file to run that command but I didn't find it. I found first the jBoss image:

```
docker exec 42f1c5c8bf55 it bash
```

then I enter on jboss

```
sh-4.4$ cd /opt/jboss
sh-4.4$ find . -name "kc.sh"
find: ‘./proc/tty/driver’: Permission denied
find: ‘./var/cache/ldconfig’: Permission denied
find: ‘./lost+found’: Permission denied
sh-4.4$ find . -name "kc.*"
find: ‘./proc/tty/driver’: Permission denied
find: ‘./var/cache/ldconfig’: Permission denied
find: ‘./lost+found’: Permission denied
```

I searched a lot and I tried different solutions, but non of them worked.

Anyone please give me a little help or at least an ideea how to implement a new feature, like token-exchange or access_token, inside keycloak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`KC_` prefixed environment variables](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features) in your Docker container. For example, to enable features:

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin123 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KC_FEATURES=token-exchange -e DB_VENDOR=H2 jboss/keycloak
```

Note that the `jboss/keycloak` image is not the current official Keycloak image anymore. You probably want to migrate to the `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` images (see [the Keycloak Docker docs](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker)).

Comment: Indeed on server I use https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/keycloak/tags not jboss. The dashboard is the same like the one from quay. I ran docker with quay.io/keacloak and on the Master Realm page I see: TOKEN_EXCHANGE - Preview. What that means? TOKEN_EXCHANGE is not available? Or if it is available, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable features using env var `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` environment variable
for example to enable Ability for admins to impersonate users just start the container like this:

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin123 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e DB_VENDOR=H2 -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.impersonation=enabled" jboss/keycloak
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the below env variable to enable token exchange feature,

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
```

My Docker compose looks like below,

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/devteam/docker_data/keycloak-data:/data
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: kc@123
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres_url
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: k_user
      DB_PASSWORD: k_pass
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled"
```